# How to make hotkeys more organized in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Do others struggle with memorizing VS Code hotkeys as I do? While I know hotkeys can be customized in settings, I'm not familiar with all of them. I even created a graphic of hotkeys, but it didn't help speed up my workflow. Any advice?

Comment: Do a lot of coding and muscle memory will do the rest for you - practice is the key

Answer (score 1):

1. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. This is the only command you have to memorize.
   ***Literally***
   every other command can be found there, with its hotkeys displayed if there is one
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]